# Why PDO data adding into header instead of insert into db?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm not sure if my code is ok, it seems ok to me but when I input data, data not insert but adding at url like index.php?firstname=Kid&lastname=Max&username=OfficialKidMax.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['memadd'])) {
    
    
    include('conn.php');
    
    

    $thisusername = $post["username"];
    $thisemail = $post["email"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = : thisusername OR `email` = : thisemail LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(['thisusername' => $thisusername] OR ['thisemail' => $thisemail]);
    $user = $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    
            if ($user) { // if user exists
    if ($user['username'] === $username) {
        array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
    }
    if ($user['email'] === $email) {
        array_push($errors, "email already exists");
    }
    
    
    if(empty($user)){
        $query = "INSERT INTO members (`usermid`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `email`, `phone`, `usernid`, `address`, `address2`, `zipcode`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array($_POST['usermid'], $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['usernid'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['address2'], $_POST['zipcode']));
        
        
        
    }
            }$_SESSION['success'] = 'Record Added';
        header( 'Location: success.php' );
```

## Update

I change my code a little bit.
Hi, thanks for your reply. I changed my code a little bit. It's work well now.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset($_POST['memadd']) && 
include('conn.php')) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `usermid` =? OR `email` =?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$_POST['usermid'], $_POST['email']]);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    
    if ($result) { // if member exists
    if ($result['email'] === [$_POST['email']]) {
        array_push($errors, "User email already exists");
    }
    if ($result['usermid'] === [$_POST["usermid"]]) {
        array_push($errors, "User ID already exists");
    }
    
    if(empty($result)){
    // I run this query code at first to check if INSERT is ok and it's worked.
    //But problem happen after if add.
        $query = "INSERT INTO members (`usermid`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `email`, `phone`, `usernid`, `address`, `address2`, `zipcode`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array($_POST['usermid'], $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['usernid'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['address2'], $_POST['zipcode']));
        
      }
    }
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Record Added';
        header( 'Location: madd.php' );
```

I think this code is ok, or maybe not because I'm getting another problem.

```
if (count($errors) > 0) : ?>
<div class="error">
<?php foreach ($errors as $error)  { ?>
 <p><?php echo $error; ?></p>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<?php  endif ?>
```

[21-Apr-2021 01:21:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /errors.php on line 1

Comment: Check your web server error log or add this to the top of you script to turn on error reporting to the browser. ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: The code you posted here won't do what you say it does. I suspect that the problem is with your form, which needs `method="POST"` added to the `<form>` tag.

Comment: Hi @JasonK , I turned on error reporting and I got Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, bool given in ../core.php on line 13

Comment: Hi @TangentiallyPerpendicular , yes I forget to do it so. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To save your self some grief learning php. These two links will help.

https://phptherightway.com/

Easy to read PDO tutorial.
https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

I did test this so there may still be some errors.

```
<?php 

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (isset($_POST['memadd'])) {
  include('conn.php');
//
// Not sure what $post is. I assumen you ment  $_POST
// Are these really needed?
//    $thisusername = $post["username"];
//    $thisemail = $post["email"];
// Removed the space after the :
// My optinion but if you habe to use the ` for anything. It's time to be more descriptive in your names.
//
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = :thisusername OR `email` = :thisemail LIMIT 1";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
//
// Not sure what the OR was doing.
//
  $stmt->execute([
    ':thisusername' => $_POST['username'], 
    ':thisemail' => $_POST['email']
  ]);
// Do you really need a second copy of the result?
  $user = $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

  if ($user) { // if user exists
    if ($user['username'] === $username) {
      array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
    }
    if ($user['email'] === $email) {
      array_push($errors, "email already exists");
    }
  
  if(empty($user)){
//
// I find usig the INSERT INTO table SET fld1=val1, fld2=val2, ...
// Much easyer to keep strack feilds and values.
//
    $query = "INSERT INTO members (`usermid`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `email`, `phone`, `usernid`, `address`, `address2`, `zipcode`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array($_POST['usermid'], $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['usernid'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['address2'], $_POST['zipcode']));        
//
// You not doing any testing. How do you know it worked?
//
    }
  }
$_SESSION['success'] = 'Record Added';
header( 'Location: success.php' );
```